# Jquery selector with specific innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector, innerhtml

`$('.select option:selected[innerHTML="5"]')`

My goal here is to select an option which is currently selected and which's innerHTML matches **exactly** a string (example : "5")

Here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kxkzU/4/

**This :** `$('.select option:selected:contains("5")')` **does not work** since then value 0.375 would match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use filter:

```
$('.select option:selected').filter(function(){
    return this.innerHTML == 5;
}).html("good");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kxkzU/5/

Also, your fiddle had `.select` as the className instead of just `select`.

Comment: This is perfect! Will check as answer as soon as I can!